# Why does Juliana seek asylum with Nazis?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

In the second season of the Man in the High Castle, Juliana seeks asylum with the Nazis. At that point it is clear that she needs to disappear from San Francisco, because

> she knows from the films it could be destroyed by the atomic bomb, and because both the Kempetai and the Resistance are after her.

It is, however, not clear to me, why she does not for instance escape to the Neutral Zone, which appears to be much safer choice?

> We also know she is searching for Dixon, but why does she want to find him so much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *"It is, however, not clear to me, why she does not for instance escape to the Neutral Zone, which appears to be much safer choice?"*

The Neutral Zone's safety is questionable at best, as seasons 1 & 3 contest by being portrayed as a "lawless" land full of criminals and bounty hunters alike, in which one doesn't have any real protection. (The Bounty Hunter known as "The Marshall", nearly killed Julianna in season 1. It took quick thinking on Joe's part to escape him)

**But really, Julianna goes to the Nazi occupied New York for 3 possible reasons:**

1. Going to the embassy to defect was the quickest thing she could do to escape the Kempetai. (Like you said, she needed to get out ASAP)
2. She's trying to find [George Dixon](https://the-man-in-the-high-castle.fandom.com/wiki/George_Dixon), because she saw him in one of the films (the one showing an alternate future) and was also questioned about him by The Man in the High Castle/Hawthorne Abendsen, as he tells her that **Dixon is vital in preventing a nuclear war**. Dixon lives in New York.
3. She probably was hoping to reunite and get help from Joe. (Her relationship with Frank continued to be a bit tumultuous, both due to the consequences for Julianna leaving Frank before and because he gets swept up with the resistance, his partnership with Robert Childan, and the Yakuza, while still dealing with The Kempetai).